# I want to change the html of breadcrumb?

Tags: html, breadcrumbs

I want to change the default HTML and some CSS classes for the breadcrumbs, where is the file for that? I want to know the path where its coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml`

As a future reference, when you cannot find a template, turn on the [template path hints](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)

Answer (score 2):

Use template Path Hint -

1. System → Configuration
2. Advanced → Developer
3. On Left Top Scope Select Your Website → Store View
4. and In right side Debug Tab
5. Select Template Path Hint to Yes